# Complete subject on first emission or when other subject emits

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a subject, that will only ever emit a single value. It represents the readiness of an angular component. In addition I have another subject which signifies an event that invalidates the readiness check. If `ready` emits, I want to execute the subscribe block, if `invalidateReady` emits I want to unsubscribe and complete `ready`.

So far I have the following code:

```js
const ready: Subject<void>();
const invalidateReady: Subject<void>();
...

ready.pipe(takeUntil(invalidateReady), first()).subscribe(next => {
  ...
})
```

However, I get a `EmptyErrorImpl` exception when I subscribe to `ready`. Essentially I want a `takeUntil` that listens to both `invalidateReady` and `first()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `take(1)` instead of `first()` as letter requires at least one emission while `take` does not.

Comment: An embarrassingly simple solution! It seems to do the trick